# Why can't I see the Printer?

Tags: networking, windows-7, printer

I have a Small Network set up as follows:
Internet>Modem>Router A
    Printer
    Workstations Dept A
    Router B
        Workstations Dept B


The issue is that the Workstations in Dept A can connect to and see the Networked printer just fine. But in Dept B, they can not see the printer when you search for it, but if you manually add it by IP, it seems to work just fine.
I assume Router B is somehow filtering out the ability to see the printer when you click "Find Printer" but I am a little stumped as to what.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Update your question. Its unclear. I think in Dept B u wanted to say, they CAN NOT see the printer during the search, otherwise I dont see any issue.

Comment: Quite right. Corrected:)

Comment: `But in Dept B, they can not see the printer when you search for it`  Tell them to open their eyes? Look in the direction of the printer?  remove the obstacle blocking their line of sight to the printer?  In all seriousness, "they can not see the printer when you search for it" is a completely useless problem description with no actual information in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router B is not filtering anything, it simply has different IP address. Seems you are connecting one router with another via WAN port. Instead, you could use first router to act as DHCP, and put them under the same IP range.
That's it.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to make an assumption that your pc's are part of a workgroup and not part of a domain.

Netbios broadcasts are not passed on by the router so you aren't going to be able to find this by name. For more information lookup broadcast domains.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain

If you want to be able to look up the printer by name than you need to implement DNS or WINS.

Probably the easiest thing is to just add it by ip on the machines behind router b.

Router A and B neither one are truly "filtering" anything, they just don't route broadcasts.

Comment: The other answer led to a working solution. But this solved the mystery for me. I'd upvote, but this account doesn't have enough whuffie. So I'll just have to settle for saying Thank you:)

Comment: Finally got enough:)